# Store a stringify serializeArray in a SQL Server database via a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string that has a bunch of double quotes that is stored in the database:

```
    {"name":"emailaddress","value":""},{"name":"eRAName","value":""}
```

What I need to do is to put a variable in between the value double quotes all inside a stored procedure.

```
    {"name":"emailaddress","value":"@email"},{"name":"eRAName","value":"@Name"}
```

The original string is created by jQuery by stringify. The double quotes need to stay in the string. I've tried '"'  and """ and various combinations.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [STUFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function to replace `""` to `"@name"` and the [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) to locate the `""`, like this:

```
declare @s varchar(100)
set @s = '{"name":"emailaddress","value":""},{"name":"eRAName","value":""}'
set @s = stuff(@s, charindex('""', @s), 2, '"@email"')
set @s = stuff(@s, charindex('""', @s), 2, '"@name"')
select @s
```

Result:

```
{"name":"emailaddress","value":"@email"},{"name":"eRAName","value":"@name"}
```

Comment: Thanks- I'll give it a try